# CakePHP - Session written on each page refresh

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I have been working on project. It was working all fine before taking update. Now it stops working on my system while it is working perfectly on other's system.

Problem - it is redirecting back to login page despite dashboard, after entering correct login credentials. It is also creating a new session on refresh of page in session folder.

Any help in highly appreciated.

Comment: Please Explain clearly .. Your question is not sufficient information. Like what you updated ? cakephp version or ?

Comment: @Cakephp.Saint Thanks for your reply. Actually different team members write code and we get that code from SVN. So after when I updated my code with newly added code, my system stops working, while others also updated their code but it is working for them

Comment: Very simple. 1. Clear your browser cache and tmp cache and try again or 2. Rename your local folder, checkout freshly in your system then it will work

Comment: @Cakephp.Saint I have tried all 3 solutions but no one worked for me :/

Comment: May be its your system problem. bec if its working for more then 2 people and not to you. May be you have updated your php version or some thing.. What about other cakephp projects are working in your system? As per my exp... Fresh checkout will work fine. If db and Folder permissions are correct

Comment: Yes I too believe so. There must be a problem with my system. The problem might lie in session Configuration but if it is so, system should not work earlier too. Other cakephp projects are also not working. I have taken fresh checkout too and all folder permissions are correct, nothing works out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62590/discussion-between-cakephp-saint-and-neha-mangla).